# How to prevent dbms_output.put_line from trimming leading whitespace?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I am trying to right-align the output of some PL/SQL code, but dbms_output.put_line is trimming the leading whitespace from my strings. How do I make it stop? Or is there a better way to output strings with leading whitespace?

```
dbms_output.put_line(lpad('string', 30, ' '));
```

outputs:

```
string
```

instead of:

```
                        string
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is not with `dbms_output` but with SQL*Plus.

Use

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON FORMAT WRAPPED
```

or

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON FORMAT TRUNCATED
```

to preserve the spaces.

---

From the [documentation (PDF)](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b12170.pdf) of `SET SERVEROUT WORD_WRAPPED` (which is the standard):

> SQL*Plus left justifies each line, skipping all leading whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

Might add that if you want to preserve the leading spaces but trim the trailing spaces use:

```
set trimspool on
```

This way the leading spaces will be preserved but the line length will be determined by the actual length of text in the output.